# I am trying to get images from other website but code is not working

Tags: php

I am new to php language it will be great to get the.
URL on text box and click on the button then show all the images from that URL in a div of your page by using object oriented PHP and regular expression.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["btnGo"])){
  $url=$_POST["txtUrl"];    
  $obj=new ImageExtractor();
  $obj->extract_image2($url);
}

//class ImageExtractor
class ImageExtractor{

 //method 1
  function extract_image($url){ 
    $html=file_get_contents($url);  
    preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+src=([\'"])([^"\']+)\1/i',$html,$matches);

    foreach($matches[2] as $image){     
    echo "<img src='".$image."' width='200' height='100' style='margin:5px;' />";
    }
  }

 //method 2
 function extract_image2($url){
    $html = file_get_contents($url);

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML($html);

    $tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');

    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
               echo "<img src='".$tag->getAttribute('src')."' width='200' height='100' style='margin:5px;' />";
    }
   }
}

?>
<form action="#" method="post">
<input type="text" name="txtUrl" value="https://yahoo.com" placeholder="Enter URL" />
<input type="submit" name="btnGo" value="Go"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Please post an example image url that is not working for you.
Are you sure the urls exist?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this code :

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["btnGo"])){
  $url=$_POST["txtUrl"];   
  $obj=new ImageExtractor();
  $obj->extract_image2($url);
}

//class ImageExtractor
class ImageExtractor{

 //method 1
  function extract_image($url){ 
    $html=file_get_contents($url);  
    preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+src=([\'"])([^"\']+)\1/i',$html,$matches);

    foreach($matches[2] as $image){     
    echo "<img src='".$url."/".$image."' width='200' height='100' style='margin:5px;' />";
    }
  }

 //method 2
 function extract_image2($url){
    $html = file_get_contents($url);
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML($html);
    $tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
               echo "<img src='".$url."/".$tag->getAttribute('src')."' width='200' height='100' style='margin:5px;' />";
    }
   }
}
?>
<form action="#" method="post">
<input type="text" name="txtUrl" value="http://tinamo.ir" placeholder="Enter URL" />
<input type="submit" name="btnGo" value="Go"/>
</form>
```

but this code dosn't work on all sites, you can leach images to your space and show that images from your space (host) 
Regards
[Soroush](http://blog.tinamo.ir)

Comment: in this line : echo "<img src='".$url."/".$tag->getAttribute('src')."' width='200' height='100' style='margin:5px;' />";